# How can I get raw keyboard input in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, input, keyboard, ascii

I know that I can use the `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, and `KeyPress` events to handle keyboard input, but the input uses ASCII input, meaning that it's not smooth (i.e. when I hold down a key, the events are repeated as if I was typing something: triggering it once, waiting half a second, and only then repeating). How can I get raw key input from the keyboard that directly checks whether or not a key is pressed down, instead of looking at the keyboard buffer?

Answer (score 0):

It's only the `KeyPress` event that looks at the keyboard buffer.

When a key is pressed the `KeyDown` event is triggered, and if it's not a control key (shift, ctrl, alt etc.) it also produces a character for the keyboard buffer which triggers the `KeyPress` event.

As long as the key is pressed, more characters will be generated for the keyboard buffer, each triggering another `KeyPress` event.

When a key is released, the `KeyUp` event is triggered.

To keep track of keys that are pressed, you use the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events. There is no way to directly check if a key is pressed or not, the keyboard only communicates with the computer by sending down and up events for keys.

Note that the `KeyDown` event is not always followed by a `KeyUp` event for the same key, but the events can overlap. Typing an uppercase A for example typically produces these `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events:

```
KeyDown for shift
KeyDown for a
KeyUp for a
KeyUp for shift
```

Comment: So, if I want to keep track of which keys are being held at a moment in time, I need to use booleans, changing their value to True on KeyDown and False on KeyUp?

Comment: @7yphoid: Exactly. Well, it doesn't have to be booleans, you could for example have a list of currently pressed keys, depending on what's convenient for your use.